# hdinsight Microsoft Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

is Microsoft "HDInsight" is free development download. the below URL says it is available to download ,but  there is no such link available on Microsoft site , can any one tell me , whether Microsoft "Hadoop" is free.

"http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-install-and-use-hdinsight-hadoop.html#.VB9uqpRdV5U"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version is called HDInsight Emulator.  You can get a copy from here, http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=HDINSIGHT

For more information on getting started, see http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-get-started-emulator/